# addChild, etc. using NSTreeController and NSTreeNode (snow leopard)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, nstreecontroller

I have a setup with an object (OTNodeDatum) (OT for OutlineTest) to be the represented object in NSTreeNode.  NSTreeNode is the Class shown in the attributes page for NSTreeController.

I have document based app, no core data.  On MyDocument init, I set up content with an NSMutableArray containing one item, an NSTreeNode with a represented object which contains a single property (yes, name).

Add button, Add Child button, Delete button, hooked up via interface builder to the NSTreeController add action, etc.

It works up to a point.

When I do an add, I get a new blank line which I can edit, but the inserted text goes away when I leave the cell.

When I do a delete, things get deleted.

When I do add child, nothing happens.

I think I have to subclass either NSTreeNode, or NSTreeController to get the right behavior in terms of adding children and adding a new represented object in addition to adding a new tree node.

IS this on the right track?  If I subclass NSTreeController would I just override the add, addChild, to get the right thing to happen?  And what could I mess up?   I can't seem to find any guidance on this, although I've spent a long time looking.

Thanks.

John V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the right way to do things, or at least, a way, is to use

```
-(void)insertObject:(id)object atArrangedOjectIndexPath:(int)index;
```

First create `representedObject`, create a new `NSTreeNode` with that represented object, then insert it.  More work than a simply connecting the add button to the tree controller, but (hopefully) the advantages of using `NSTreeNode` make up for it.